# Add method not returning any values

Tags: c++, linked-list, addition

I am writing an add method for a Linked List class in C++. The add method is written to handle a variety of situations that may occur based on the input of the method.  I have added "cout" statements in order to try and track which loops/if-statements the method is going into, but nothing is being printed from the method.  The input for the method are the index of the node and the data that is held in the node.

```
void linkedList::add(int pos, string item)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    Node *nextTemp = new Node;

    if(pos == 0)
    {
        cout<< "hey";
        if(head != NULL)
        {
            cout<< "hey1";
            temp->setData((head->getPosition()+1), 
                    head->getItem(), head->getNextNode());
            head->setData(pos, item, temp);
            currentNode = head;
            size++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<< "hey2";
            head->setData(pos, item, temp);
            currentNode = head;
            size++;
        }
    }
    else if(pos == size)
    {
        cout<< "hey3";
        while(currentNode != NULL)
        {
            cout<< "hey4";
            currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
        }
        temp->setData(pos, item, nextTemp);
        currentNode->nextNode = temp;
        size++;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<< "hey5";
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cout<< "hey6";
            if(i == currentNode->getPosition())
            {
                cout<< "hey7";
                temp->setData(currentNode->getPosition(), 
                        currentNode->getItem(), currentNode->getNextNode());
                currentNode->setData(pos, item, temp);
                size++;
            }

            currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
            while(currentNode->getPosition() < (size+1))
            {
                cout<< "hey8";
                currentNode->setPosition(i+1);
                currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's `void`, do you expect it to return values?

Comment: No, the method is not supposed to return anything. Just simply create and add the new Node with the method inputs to the linked list.

Comment: If you add a print outside the ifs? what happens then? If nothing, then you need to show us how you call it.

Comment: You need to add an `<< endl` to the end of your `cout`s since `stout` is line-buffered.

Comment: Append a newline, perhaps it's simply buffered.

Comment: I realize this is outside the scope of the original question, but can anyone spot any logic errors within this method?

Comment: Yes: Not all code paths insert temp and/or nextTemp into the list, therefore the prog leaks memory.

Comment: How do I solve the memory leak problem? I'm assuming with a destructor of some sort, but I'm not sure how to use a destructor.

Comment: A memory leak occurs when you dynamically allocate memory (e.g., with the `new` operator), but never *de*-allocate it (e.g., with the `delete` operator). In other words: for every `new` you have, you should have a corresponding `delete`. As @PeterSchneider mentioned, there are parts of your `add` method that don't insert `new`ly allocated nodes in the list. As a result, this method is the only thing that knows these objects exist, and as such is the only thing that can `delete` them.